# I am trying to make an Object in Arduino but got an error

Tags: c++, string, object, arduino, type-conversion

I am trying to make an object in Arduino but I have an error in setting up `myObject`.

```
struct myObject {
  char dataA[32];
  char dataB[32];
};

make_object("Hello","World");


void make_object(String strText1, String strText2){


  myObject vars = { 
     strText1,                 // here are my errors
     strText2                  // here are my errors  
  };
  Serial.println(vars.dataA);
  Serial.println(vars.dataB);
}
```

The error is:

> no suitable conversion function from "String" to "char" exists

Does someone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

[`string.toCharArray(buf, len)` function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/functions/tochararray/) seems useful.

```
void make_object(String strText1, String strText2){


  myObject vars;
  strText1.toCharArray(vars.dataA, sizeof(vars.dataA));
  strText2.toCharArray(vars.dataB, sizeof(vars.dataB));
  Serial.println(vars.dataA);
  Serial.println(vars.dataB);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@MikeCAT

Thanks a lot that worked.

With your help I was able to store SSID object to EEPROM

```
struct wifiConn {
  char eSsid[32];
  char ePasw[32];
};

void write_wifi_toEEPROM(uint8_t startAddr, String strSSID, String strPW){
  wifiConn vars;
  strSSID.toCharArray(vars.eSsid, sizeof(vars.eSsid));
  strPW.toCharArray(vars.ePasw, sizeof(vars.ePasw));
  EEPROM.put(startAddr, vars);
  EEPROM.commit();  
}
wifiConn read_wifi_fromEEPROM(uint8_t startAddr){
  wifiConn readEE;        //Variable to store custom object read from EEPROM.
  EEPROM.get(startAddr, readEE);
  Serial.println("Read ssid object from EEPROM ");
  return readEE;    
}
```

I hope the code will also help other users.